# What are the pro and cons of having localization files vs hard coded variables in source code?

Tags: java, file, localization, variables

Definitions:

Files:

Having the localization phrases stored in a physical file that gets read at application start-up and the phrases are stored in the memory to be accessed via util-methods. The phrases are stored in key-value format. One file per language.

Variables:

The localization texts are stored as hard code variables in the application's source code. The variables are complex data types and depending on the current language, the appropriate phrase is returned.

Background:

The application is a Java Servlet and the developers use Eclipse as their primary IDE.

Some brief pro and cons:

Since Eclipse is use, tracking and finding unused localizations are easier when they are saved as variables, compared to having them in a file. However the application's source code becomes bigger and bloated.

**What are the pro and cons of having localization text in files versus hard coded varibles in source code? What do you do and why?**

Update 1: In my specific case, recompiling and deploying is not an issue, since it is done since we have test-phases that gives us a chance to find typos, etc. Because of that we rarely need to change the phrases once the application is on production.

Comment: when you are refering to "hard code variables" do you mean static finals?

Comment: In my situation, no, since we still want the chance to change their values during runtime - just in case.

Comment: And, do you mean by "in source code" that you're not localizing at all? Or that you have a series of .java files somewhere that are basically container classes for a string map?

Comment: Correct. Within the source code, I have variables containing the phrases, which I can use in "render" methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having the localization of app in its source code has many disadvantages - probably the biggest being, that when you want to fix/add/remove some localization, you have to recompile it and redistribute a new version. With separate files, the updates are more flexible, faster and easier to maintain and of course others can add localization to your app without the need to have access to the code.

So i would recommend going with the separate files option, not hardcoding it into the app.

Comment: In ideal world, your config files would go through just as rigorous a change management process as source files. (code is code)  However, I have found that usually there are fewer controls around configuration, and fixes can be pushed out faster.

Comment: For my specific situation, recompiling and deploying is done daily anyway. We never need to update the localization files without doing a recompile/deploy.

Comment: Even in this case i would recommend going with files. Your situation may change in the future and when the project is finished, maintaining it will become easier. The last argument would be something like: "its good practice". Moreover, you can still have localization files under version control and work with them as if they were real source code.

Comment: I believe the benefits of having them as source code variables is greater, since it would be both easier to locate a translation in the system and easier to locate deprecated/unused translations. And you won't need yet another layer between the system and the localizations.

Comment: As you said above, you have the strings in a separate java file in a string map. Now consider that you "rename" the java file to a .txt file and load its contents into a string map at runtime. Apart from a small overhead, is there any other drawback i'm missing? Anyway, both solutions are ok (they will work), I would just preffer the one with files instead of hardcoded variables, and thats all what my answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

If your project will be used by hundreds of people, localization is worth it because odds are some of them are more familiar with another language. If this project is only for internal use, then hardcoded variables are okay. If the number of users is below 100, the tasks of finding translators and maintaining each localization file are too cumbersome.

Comment: I would like to have pro and cons :)

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no choice between "Files" and "Variables". Because it should be always "Files".

pros:

a) Easy to maintain - The entire localization is in a single file.

b) No recompile required when there is a change.

c) Easy to introduce another language.

1. Usually translators are
   non-technical people.
2. Not necessary to change in
   multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have localized versions of your program, then most likely you'll need a translator at some point. If you do not have localization files, you have to give the translator access to every source file with string resources (do you even know which they are?) and then you'll need to modify the source manually, which is prone for error.

Comment: Export/import tools can be developed for these things. In our specific case, the application goes through a test phase were the testers find translation-bugs while testing and report them to development. Giving them files to translate would cost more due to 1) They will have to go through and translate phrases that could be unused in the system 2) It's hard to translate correctly without knowing the context.

Comment: @corgrath: regarding your first point, you only need to use localization files for actual resources that will be visible to the user. Regarding your second point, you are absolutely correct. But source code will not be a proper context for a translator anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For large software companies, the localization process has traditionally been performed by a separate group from the development team (often in a different country). The localization group would often work with binaries - hence the requirement for resource bundles to be separate artefacts. One of the goals of the process is to not let translators break source code; another is to not let programmers break strings.

From your comments, it sounds like you have tools to do some alternative form of automated String extraction and insertion. This might be a viable alternative if done right.

Questions I'd be asking about your translation process:

- Do you have tools to automate resource extraction and file rewriting?

  - Any cutting and pasting of strings (especially strings you can't understand) is likely to be a vector for bugs.
  - Can these tools distinguish between resource strings and untranslatable strings?
- Are you giving translators a standard file format they have the tools to work with?
- Do you have tools/processes for String recovery from previous versions?
- Is the size of the source code increasing significantly because you're adding translations?

  - When it comes to application logic, the strings are clutter you don't want to see and there's something to be said for separating logic and presentation data
- Is this approach going to scale if you add more languages?
- Are you introducing any encoding, keyboard or font issues?

  - There's not much point hard-coding strings if your editors break them
  - You can overcome the lack of character support using `\uXXXX` escaping

Long-lived products can accumulate unused resources, but I've never seen it become a practical problem. If you feel strongly about it, you can probably detect unused keys by scanning the sources.